# how can i save content of current webpage in word through php

Tags: php, ms-word, html

i need to save contents of webpage on word. i need to keep the links and formating too. if i send

```
$ter=$ter. "<a href='$url'>".$chunk."</a> ";
 $fp  =  fopen("test.doc",  'w+'); 
        $str  =  $ter;

        fwrite($fp,  $str); 

        fclose($fp);
```

i get  a word document but i loose the links ..it comes out as

```
a href='http://www.google.com/search?q=sells+sea+shells%0D%0A'>sells sea shells
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going along with this weird pretend ".doc" file which Word (2007) does seem to display as a document; if I change your fwrite line:

```
fwrite($fp,  '<html><body>' . $str . '</body></html>');
```

It works.

Comment: I think it works because Word reads the file, and notices that it isn't actually in the .doc file format. So, it then tries to guess what kind of file it is and realizes it's HTML, so it handles it as such. If you open your generated file in Word, save it again, and then open the saved file in Notepad, you will see that Word has saved it as (it's own brand of extremely convoluted) HTML. Despite the .doc extension.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to take a look at this: http://phpword.codeplex.com/

Comment: For a more elaborate explanation of the technique mentioned above, check this article - codeproject.com/kb/office/Wordyna.aspx